# xmpp chat client for raspbian to send and receive messages & files cross platform devices

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, cross-compilation, communication

I have setup XMPP Prosody a communication-chat server on my raspberry pi 3.

It works great! I have installed chat clients Adium on Mac and Astrachat on iPhone and Android phone.
AstraChat client is great it lets me share files and make voice call but is limited to Astrachat only, and it's also not available for debian and mac platform.

Is there chat server-clients applications which are cross platform and can share files across multiple devices without any much of a hassle?

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to send messages from Raspberry Pi to mobile clients I would suggest you "Youwsup". Its a whatsapp messenger integration for Raspberry Pi. It worked well for me. However if you are looking for integrating your application with desktop clients then you should look for some other alternatives. I would suggest mqtt with mosquitto.

I am not sure if you already checked this https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup.

I would suggest pidgin client for the xmpp chat client. I have used it on debian. So it should work on raspbian as well. You can use keysync lib for any program communication. Also there are some reference articles in hackday.io (https://hackaday.io/project/4849-raspberry-pi-jabberxmpp-client)

Comment: I am looking for xmpp chat client on raspbian to send and receive files to my iphone or windows phone